# What is the suggested playing order of Star wars Jedi Knights games?

Tags: star-wars-jedi-knight-series

I own the following Star wars games

1. Dark Forces
2. Jedi Knight: Dark Forces 2
3. Jedi Knight: Mysteries of the Sith
4. Jedi Knight 2: Jedi Outcast
5. Jedi Knight: Jedi Academy

What is the proper playing order of these games regarding the storyline? Also am I missing any game that is part of the storyline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so if you want to play your games in the chronological order.

- Dark Forces - 0 BBY - 1 ABY
- Jedi Knight: Dark Forces II - 5 ABY
- Jedi Knight: Mysteries of the Sith - 10 ABY
- Jedi Knight II: Jedi Outcast - 12 ABY
- Jedi Knight: Jedi Academy - 14 ABY

Which is the entire series of Jedi Knight games. If you are curious in the slightest you can check out the chronological timeline I found and used as my source for this.

Source: [Star Wars Video Game Timeline](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Legends_video_games)